# How to chain apply functions to subset a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, apply

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to subset based on the application of two functions `is_long()` and `is_short()`.  The first must return True, and the second must return True in order for the row to be subset. For exapmle:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['foo', 10], ['baar', 15], ['baz', 14], ['baaar', 15]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age'])
df

def is_long(x):
    assert isinstance(x, str)
    return True if len(x) > 2 else False


def is_short(x):
    assert isinstance(x, str)
    return True if len(x) < 4 else False
```

The following should return rows of `name` that have a length of 3:

```
df[df['name'].apply(is_long).apply(is_short)]
```

should return:

```
    name    age
0   foo     10
2   baz     14
```

but the second apply is not performed on a dataframe as it returns an assertion error:

```
   11 
     12 def is_short(x):
---> 13     assert isinstance(x, str)
     14     return True if len(x) < 4 else False

AssertionError:
```

My question is - how does one elegantly chain together two apply functions (without writing two separate lines of code) so that they are acting on the same column and are executed in sequence?

Any advice here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it by `apply()` method then

instead of:

```
df[df['name'].apply(is_long).apply(is_short)]
```

Do/Use this:

```
 df[df.loc[df['name'].apply(is_long),'name'].apply(is_short)]
```

**OR**

```
df[df['name'].apply(lambda x: is_long(x) & is_short(x))]
```

output of above method:

```
#output

    name    age
0   foo     10
2   baz     14
```

**Explaination:**

In your code:`df[df['name'].apply(is_long).apply(is_short)]`

`df['name'].apply(is_long)` gives a `boolean series` of `True` and you are passing that boolean series to `is_short()` function by chaining another `apply()` method to it and that's why you are getting `AssertionError` because your used `assert` keyword in your `is_short()` function and your condition `isinstance(x, str)` is not satisfying

Comment: Yes, thanks, but the point is not to get 3 but rather to apply functions one after another.  That is just an example.

Comment: Updated my answer...kindly have a look

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap those two functions in a function in the `lambda` sense i.e.:

```py
df[df.name.apply(lambda x: is_long(x) and is_short(x))]
```

to get

```
  name  age
0  foo   10
2  baz   14
```